# Oracle DBlink creation to fetch data from MySql

Tags: mysql, oracle, dblink

I am trying to create Oracle DB link (using plsql developer) to fetch data from Mysql server. Can you please suggest me how to do that and also let me know if i need to install any software or drivers. Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install Oracle gateway software.  I suggest going to support.oracle.com and search for dg4odbc and download the software. There is some setup that needs to be done on the database server side before a dblink can be created. Carefully read the documentation.